# Замена стандартного файлового менеджера в браузере

Tags: google-chrome, администрирование, vi

Я полагаю, возможно вам известно как заменить nautilus, представимый как стандартизированный в google browser, на ranger?

> Непосредственный виновник выше приводимого вопроса, благодарю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть, Вы хотите, что бы хром открывал консольку с Вашим любимым файловым менеджером?

Comment: Если это возможно, как нечто с навигацией vi

Comment: я не знаю, поддерживает ли ranger возможность быть в качестве окна сохранения (скорее всего нет). Поэтому, придется видимо дописывать сам файловый менеджер, а потом уже подменять вызовы для хрома.